# Is there any test to check variance stationarity in time series?

Tags: time-series, variance, stationarity, heteroscedasticity

The question is straightforward: Is there any test to check variance stationarity (homoscedasticity) in time series?

And, if it exists, which are its implementations in R or Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for white noise (a stronger condition than stationarity), you can use a Ljung and Box test in R (see `Box.test`).

If you want to test for just stationarity, econometrics also has the KPSS test, allowing you to test for level stationarity or trend stationarity - see `kpss.test` in the tseries R library.

The idea behind KPSS, as I understand it, is that you fit the model

$$
X_t = \xi t + \eta_t + \epsilon_t,\ \eta_t = \eta_{t-1} + w_t,\ w_t\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim}(0, \sigma^2)
$$

then KPSS tests either:

1. for level stationarity, i.e. that $\sigma=0$ and $\xi=0$ (then $X_t$ is stationary), or
2. for trend stationarity, i.e. that $\sigma=0$ (then $X_t - \xi t$ is stationary)

Though KPSS will only be decent if the above model is sensible.

(I don't know about Python implementations, I'm sure there are equivalents to the R versions though)

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but I was looking for a contrast to test the existence of constant variance (homoscedasticity), as KPSS or Dickey-Fuller tests allow to test the existence of trend-level stationarity.

Comment: You could model the variance with (G)ARCH and then use KPSS, but with level stationarity: `kpss.test(data, null="Level")`

Comment: Okey. I was looking for a simplier method, but maybe it does not exist. Could it be possible to detect heteroscedasticity using, for example, a test like `ArchTest(data)`?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239060/interpretation-of-breusch-pagan-test-bptest-in-r there is the Breusch-Pagan test that ought to be simpler. But I wonder if it is necessary to run this test, and instead check that your residuals are stationary/white noise

Comment: Okey, thanks a lot!

Comment: -1 since the answer does not seem to address the actual question.